# How real an issue is static for hobbyists (Arduino etc.) for parts storage?

Tags: esd, antistatic, storage, static

The parts I buy come in all kinds of packaging:

[image: parts in antistatic bags]

Here we have a USB charger in a basic anti-static bag, Kapton tape and MOSFETs in ESD bags and a small development board in a plain plastic bag.

I'm pretty confident the Kapton tape could have been safely shipped without an ESD bag! But for other parts, I'm not so sure.

So my question is - **when it comes to storage can I fairly safely chuck most of the kind of parts a hobbyist would use into something like this**:

[image: plastic storage bins]

By hobbyist, I mean someone doing small Arduino-style projects with LEDs, motors and the like.

Or should the plastic storage containers and their potential for static worry me even as a hobbyist? If it should worry me, is there anything I can easily do about it? E.g. would it be enough to line the bottom of the containers with conductive foam like this:

[image: conductive foam]

My impression (perhaps false) is that most hobbyist parts are fairly static-safe. The fact that a company like Sparkfun is OK shipping small development boards in plain plastic bags *suggests* to me that maybe this isn't such a big issue?

Are there particular parts that someone like me needs to look out for, e.g. most large thru-hole parts are fine but one should look out for X?

I'm primarily interested in storage - I do all my work on an anti-static mat (that I have connected to a radiator) but I'm starting to accumulate enough parts that I want to get them more organized (and so just bought the parts bin seen above).

Comment: Put that dev board in an anti-static bag. Use the one the Kapton tape came in if need be. Anything with a CMOS IC or a MOSFET, ditto laser diode needs static control; and not much else does (not sure about new LEDs but they didn't used to).

Comment: The issue with **ESD** (not static, a **static** charge doesn't **do** anything). Is that it can damage things that you'll only see later, like weeks after the ESD event. I largely "ignore" most ESD measures for hobby projects and never had issues. In my **professional life** of course I do take ESD extremely seriously. Learn more about "static" and ESD by watching this (long but extremely educational) video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uk5F3rQNUkU  just posted by Dave from the EEVBlog.